# how to solve this logic

Tags: c#

Write a function which takes a string input and removes all the characters which appear more than or equal to the given number.

> `RemoveCharacters("Spanish", 2)` should return **"panih"**
>
> `RemoveCharacters("Spanish", 3)` should return **"Spanish"**

```
  string text = "Spanish";

  var sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);

  int maxCount = 2;
  int currentCount = 2;
  char specialChar = 'S';

  foreach (char c in text)
    if (c != specialChar || ++currentCount <= maxCount)
      sb.Append(c);

  text = sb.ToString();
               
  int commasFound = 0; 
  int maxCommas = 1;

  text = new string(text.Where(c => c != 'S' || ++commasFound <= maxCommas).ToArray());

  Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Doesn´t this code work as you expect? If so, what *does* it return and what did you expect instead?

Comment: "panish"  its show like that... i want login of above question

Answer (score 1):

Let's process the string in *two* steps:

1. Find out characters to remove (which apperas more or equal than `count` times)
2. Remove such characters from the string.

Implemenattaion

```
private static String RemoveCharacters(string value, int count) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;
  else if (count <= 1)
    return "";

  HashSet<char> toRemove = new HashSet<char>(value
    .GroupBy(c => char.ToUpper(c))
    .Where(chunk => chunk.Count() >= count)
    .Select(chunk => chunk.Key));

  return string.Concat(value.Where(c => !toRemove.Contains(char.ToUpper(c))));
}
```

Some tests:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "Spanish",
  "bla-bla-bla",
  "Abracadabra",
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,-15} => '{RemoveCharacters(test, 2)}'"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
Spanish         => 'panih' // S is removed
bla-bla-bla     => ''      // all characters are removed
Abracadabra     => 'cd'    // A, b, r are removed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not writing your homework for you, but consider using a dictionary. Iterate the characters in your word. If it exists in your dictionary, increment that element. Otherwise insert it in your dictionary with a value of 1. Then iterate your dictionary keys and note which ones exceed your target. Finally, write out your string excluding those characters.